# Armazenar 10 valores em R

Tags: r

Bom dia a todos, tenho que fazer um exercício onde tenho que armazenar 10 valores digitados repetidamente e dizer quantos são negativos e positivos.
Preciso usar o comando while mas não sei como fazer para armazenar estes valores.

Comment: você tentou resolver esse exercício de alguma maneira? coloque o seu código para exemplificar

Answer (score 2):

Tente o seguinte:

```
conta <- 0
x <- numeric(0)
while(conta < 10){
    y <- scan(nmax = 1)
    x <- c(x, y)
    conta <- conta + 1
}

positivo <- x[x > 0]
negativo <- x[x < 0]
zero <- x[x == 0]
```

Agora se quiser saber quantos são os positivos, negativos ou zero (que falta na pergunta?) basta usar `length`.

```
length(positivo)
length(negativo)
length(zero)
```

Para os ver,

```
positivo
negativo
zero
```